# Custom Counter Longtable

Tags: tables, longtable, counters

I would like to create a custom `counter` for the following table such that it appears "Table 6.1: Sample Statistics: Swiss Model". In other words, I would like to manually input the counter settings.

I tried with `\renewcommand\thetable`, but it is not working. Would you know how to do it?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{booktabs, longtable}

\begin{document}
\small\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4.5pt}
\sisetup{table-format=2.4}
\begin{longtable}{@{}l*{6}{S}}
    \renewcommand\thetable{6.1}
    \caption{Sample Statistics: Swiss Model}
    \label{my-label}\\
    \toprule
    \textbf{Descriptive Statistic} & {$rtb_t$ }&{$xr_t$} & {$xb_t$} & {$y_t$ }& {$(d-p)_t$}& {$spr_t$} \\
    \endfirsthead
    %
    \endhead
    %
    \toprule
    ~~Mean  & 0.0091 &  0.0274 & 0.0244 & 0.0107 &  0.0309 &  0.0096\\
    ~~Standard Deviation & 0.0096  &  0.1310  & 0.0284  & 0.0110  &  0.0035  &  0.0055\\
    ~~Variance & 0.0001  &  0.0172  &  0.0008  &  0.0001   &  0.0000  &  0.0000\\
    ~~Skewness &  0.1595 &  -0.5744  & 0.3437  &  0.3966  & -0.9990   & 1.4322\\
    ~~Kurtosis & 2.8890   & 3.4555  &  4.3478  &  1.9406 &  4.4613  & 4.9241\\
    ~~Sharpe Ratio & {-}  & 0.2091 & 0.8582 & {-} &{-}  &{-}\\
    \bottomrule 
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you please explain a little more details, what you want to achieve? At least for me the question in quite unclear. And your MWE won’T work as ist doesn’t load `longtable` and `booktabs`. Pleas always make sure to have a compilable MWE (if the question is not about a compilation error of curse).

Comment: Just edited @Tobi

Comment: I’m sorry but I still don’t get it. What would you like to input in the code? Do you just want long tables numbers indecent of normal tables?

Comment: One of the sections I have in the paper has no counter number, e.g. Appendix (no: 6 Appendix). So the table will present "Table .1:Sample Statistics: Swiss Model" as caption, but I would like to have "Table 6.1: Sample Statistics: Swiss Model". In the tabular environment I was able to do this with \renewcommand\thetable, but with long table does not work.

Comment: Please add what you tried to the MWE. As far as I know `longtable` uses `\thetable` and thus the redefinition should work here too.

Comment: @Tobi I adapted the code with \thetable as well. Please let me know if you find a solution!

Comment: Your example is still not working! It misses `siunitx` and `array` … however both has nothing to to with the problem and thus the related code, i.e. `S` columns and `*` operator in column definition, could be completly stripped from the example. (In fact the same applies for booktabs).

Answer (score 1):

My actual answer is: **don’t do it!** In general it is a pretty bad idea to fiddle with counter manually. And what should happen when you ad another table later on or another chapter? You’ll have to manually renumber all the tables manually. Furthermore for the reader it could be quite confusing to see `6.1` and assuming it belongs to Chapter 6 but he can’t finde such a chapter.

If you still want/need to have an unnumbered appendix heading, you might consider changing the counter to something like `Apx.1` and still let TeX do the numbering by adding this change of `\thetable` to `\appendix`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{longtable}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\appto{\appendix}{%
   \setcounter{table}{0}%
   \renewcommand{\thetable}{Apx.\arabic{table}}%
}

\begin{document}

% document with normal numbered tables here

\appendix
% appendix frome here on with odd numbered tables

\begin{longtable}{l}
    \caption{Sample Statistics: Swiss Model}
    \label{my-label}\\
    \textbf{Descriptive Statistic} \\
    \endfirsthead
    content \\
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

---

If you insist on doing your manual changes simply move the redefinition of `\thetable` outside of `{longtable}` and enclose everything in a group to keep the changes local.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}
\begingroup
\renewcommand\thetable{6.1}
\begin{longtable}{l}
    \caption{Sample Statistics: Swiss Model}
    \label{my-label}\\
    \textbf{Descriptive Statistic} \\
    \endfirsthead
    content \\
\end{longtable}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```